# Classic ASP Redirect URL using variable

Tags: url, asp-classic, response.redirect

I have a variable tag <%test_variable%> that was from a resultset.

I want to use this <%=test_variable%> to redirect to a link, say

```
http://www.helloworld.someurl.com/testUrl?somevariable=<%=test_variable%>&test=ok
```

How can I do this in the <% %> tag? For example,

```
<%=test_variable%> 

<%
' I want to redirect the url with the above tag, something like:

Response.Redirect(" http://www.helloworld.someurl.com/testUrl?somevariable=<%=test_variable%>&test=ok")
%>
```

But I don't think we can have "nested tags", right?

I'm pretty new to ASP.

Comment: Make your question clear.You want to redirect to some page. If there is something you want to send to that url?

Answer (score 3):

`<%= %>` is shorthand for `<% Response.Write(" ... "); %>`:

```
http://www.helloworld.someurl.com/testUrl?somevariable=<%=test_variable%>&test=ok
```

After your clarification:

```
<%
    Response.Redirect("http://www.helloworld.someurl.com/testUrl?somevariable="
                     + test_variable
                     + "&test=ok");
%>
```

Comment: Erm, I don't think you understand my question... I want to do this: Variable: <%test_variable%> <% Response.Redirect("helloworld.someurl.com/..<%=test_variable%>;) %> but we can't have 2 consecutive tags? – prog rice bowl 1 min ago edit

Comment: Just note that if you're using VBScript as your server-side language (which is more common in Classic ASP), then you should use `&` instead of `+` to concatenate the strings together.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.helloworld.someurl.com/testUrl?somevariable=" & test_variable & "&test=ok")
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your suggestions...

I've decided to use this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.location =  "http://www.helloworld.someurl.com/testUrl?somevariable="+<%=test_variable%>+"&test=ok"
</script>
```

Comment: this will work, but note that you'll be doing a client-side redirect now and not a server-side one anymore.